# Can I use 近くif I am close to a person with my feelings?

Tags: meaning, words

I know that chikaku means close, but does it only apply to distance between things or emotions as well. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you can include the sentence you are trying to use ちかく in, so that we know whether you are using it adverbially or as a noun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, you can.  In fact, that is an important meaning of 「近{ちか}い」.  Any good monolingual dictionary would give「親密{しんみつ}な」 ("***intimate***") as one of the definitions of the word.

Read definition #3 in [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%BF%91%E3%81%84-565217#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89).

「近い」 can express closeness in all of the following:

・ physical space　「コンビニに近い」 = "near a convenience store"

・ time　「春{はる}が近い」 = "Spring is near/approaching."

・ **interpersonal and/or emotional relationship**  **「あなたともっと近い関係{かんけい}になりたいの！」 = "I want to have an (emotionally) closer relationship with you!"**

・ blood/biological relationship　「近い親戚{しんせき}・遠{とお}い親戚」 = "close & remote relatives"

・ similarity in general / almost same  「完璧{かんぺき}に近い」 = "almost pefect"

, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to comment on the conjugated form ちかく presented by OP. Whether it's used as an adverb (ちかく~) or a noun (~のちかく).

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't use 近い/近く for the condition of friend-relation, even it's grammatically correct. But Japanese says, 縁が遠くなった/身近な存在/親しくなった/仲良くしている sounds very normal.

"あなたの身近な存在になりたい" would often be a song lyrics or poems. Anyway,

近い関係 = in the same bloodline, can't recognize the difference between A and B, good relation between countries